# UIViewController presentViewController modal not animating in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, presentviewcontroller

Calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` does not animate in iOS7. The view just instantly appears. Animation works properly in iOS8. The present method is called in three different places in my app and they all display this behavior. It happens on both device and simulator.

The subsequent call to `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` animates properly in all iOS versions.

### Code Structure

The view controller calling the present method is the root view controller of a `UINavigationController`, and this navigation controller is one of the `viewControllers` in a `UITabBarController`.

Each call is simple, and is triggered by a button press. Here is one of the cases:

`GenreViewController *controller = [[GenreViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];`

### Attempted Fixes

- Explicitly dispatching to the main thread
- Calling `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]` before presentation
- Adding a delay to displaying the controller (just to see what would happen)

In each case the behavior was unchanged.
Any help would be hugely appreciated!

## UPDATE - FIX

It turns out that the `UITabBarController` had the `modalPresentationStyle` property being set to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`. This will not animate in iOS7, and you must use a presentation style of `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` instead.

Comment: did you override init method for your GenreViewController? maybe you should try GenreViewController *vc = [[GenreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([GenreViewController class]) bundle:nil];

Comment: @Doro I tried initWithNibName:bundle: (and made sure my superclasses all called it as well), but the presentation still didn't animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `UITabBarController` had the `modalPresentationStyle` property being set to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`. This will not animate in iOS7, and you must use a presentation style of `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you may use this

```
   GenreViewController *addController = [[GenreViewController alloc]

                       init];
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]

                             initWithRootViewController:addController];

   [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: Same behavior, the controller does not animate in.

Comment: Use set modal transition style as given below, it may work.

[navigationController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];

Comment: No luck, still no presentation animation using UIModalPresentationPageSheet (both presenting the navigation controller and presenting the view controller directly).

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment

As per my knowledge this animation is not possible without NavigationController. If you have created all the things programatically then also you needs to create NavigationController programatically and have to assign one of ViewController as a root ViewController. Then going for presentViewController.

Make Global UINavigationController in appDelegate
and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
InitialViewController *initialVC = [[InitialViewController alloc] init];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:initialVC];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And Then get your Appdelegate Navigation controller in specific ViewController where you want to make presentaion.

May be what you have created NavigationController is improper in Navigation Hierarchy.

Comment: It was build without storyboard, all views and controllers are created programatically.

Comment: I do programmatically create a UINavigationController and assign the view controller as the rootViewController. This is done before the present method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this :

```
GenreViewController *controller = [[GenreViewController alloc] init];
controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // or some color of your choice
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And see if it works. As which I feel might be the problem while using UIViewController programatically

Comment: No luck, still no presentation animation.